# node express app.all can't route to required module

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have 2 files:
extfile.js

```
routes = require('express').Router();
function CB (req,res) { res.send('Hello from file'); };
routes.all('/', CB);
module.exports = routes;
```

And app.js:

```
App = require('express')();
CB2 = require('./extfile');

function CB (req,res) { res.send('Hello world'); };

App.all('/', CB);      // Fine     Alt 1
App.all('/', CB2);      // Fine!   Alt 2 
App.all('/test', CB);  // Fine
App.all('/t2', CB2);   // Gives:  "Cannot GET /t2"  ???

App.listen(3000);
```

( 1st or 2nd needs to be commented out for testing.)
All except the last works fine.
What surprises me is that I get "`Cannot GET /t2`" as an error.

What am I doing wrong? ( And why are the other 3 variants working...?)